# Creating consistent Cloud Datastore backup

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, database-backups

Is it possible to create consistent (point-in-time) backup of a Google Cloud Datastore?

There is a backup tool provided by Google: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin?csw=1#backup_and_restore
Does anyone know, if this creates a consistent (point-in-time) backup?

If the records in the backup belong to various points-in-time, the value of the backup is questionable, I think.

Comment: It simple uses mapreduce to extract all your entities. If you want a consistent backup -- temporary disable writes to your datastore.

Comment: A daily scheduled read-only mode is not really an option for any real-world  consumer service...

Comment: Can you provide any links on the databases which can provide consistent backups during the load?

Comment: I think all serious relational databases (Oracle, MS SQL) have consistent (point-in-time) backup.

Comment: ...this is called 'hot backup'. Even some file systems have this capability, eg. NTFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy).

Answer (score 0):

Not currently without disabling writes.